# Typing function when decorator change return type

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing, pyre-check

how to correctly write types for the function whose return type is modified by decorator ?

Simple example:

```py
def example_decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(data):
        res = fn(data)
        return ', '.join(res)

    return wrapper


@example_decorator
def func(data: list):  # -> ???? str ? list ?
    new_data = data
    new_data.append('XYZ')
    return new_data


# When we type func -> list

def test() -> str:
    result = func(['ABC', 'EFG'])
    print(type(result))  # <class 'str'>
    return result  # Incompatible return type [7]: Expected str but got list.


test()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be a typechecker problem. Solution below.  With **mypy** its ok but **pycharm** and **pyre-check** is complaining.

```py
from typing import *

def example_decorator(
    fn: Callable[[List[str]], List[str]]
) -> Callable[[List[str]], str]:
    def wrapper(data: List[str]) -> str:
        res = fn(data)
        return ', '.join(res)

    return wrapper


@example_decorator
def func(data: List[str]) -> List[str]:  
    data.append('XYZ')
    return data


def test() -> str:
    result = func(['ABC', 'EFG'])
    print(type(result))  # <class 'str'>
    return result


test()
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a list, so like this:

```
@example_decorator
def func(data: list) -> list:
    new_data = data
    new_data.append('XYZ')
    return new_data
```

Comment: Yes but result is str: so shuld I write
result: str = func() ?

Comment: Your `wrapper` in `example_decorator` returns a string, not `func` itself