# Typing function when decorator change generic return type

Tags: python, generics, mypy

This is similar to [Typing function when decorator change return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409421/typing-function-when-decorator-change-return-type) but this time with a **generic return type**:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Generic, Callable, Any, cast

T = TypeVar('T')

class Container(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, item: T):
        self.item: T = item

def my_decorator(f: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[..., Container[T]]:

    def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Container[T]:
        return Container(f(*args, **kwargs))

    return cast(Callable[..., Container[T]], wrapper)

@my_decorator
def my_func(i: int, s: str) -> bool: ...

reveal_type(my_func) # Revealed type is 'def (*Any, **Any) -> file.Container[builtins.bool*]
```

Which mypy sorcery is required to keep the **argument types** intact for `my_func`?

Using [`typing.Protocol`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols) looks promising, but I don't see how to make it work.

Comment: See https://github.com/ceph/ceph/pull/39131 for my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick update on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65937450/1720199) and the final state of [PEP612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/), the current form is the following:

```py
def my_decorator(f: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, Container[R]]:

    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> Container[R]:
        return Container(f(*args, **kwargs))

    return wrapper
```

It seems using both explicit `P.args` and `P.kwargs` types in the decorated function is mandatory. The complete code example would be:

```py
from typing import (
    Callable,
    Generic,
    ParamSpec,
    TypeVar,
)

T = TypeVar("T")

class Container(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, item: T):
        self.item: T = item

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


def my_decorator(f: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, Container[R]]:
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> Container[R]:
        return Container(f(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def my_func(i: int, s: str) -> bool:
    ...
```

Which gives the expected typing for `my_func`:

```py
(function) def my_func(
    i: int,
    s: str
) -> Container[bool]
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `Callable[..., T]` is currently the best way to annotate this.

PEP 612 introduces `ParamSpec`, which can be used similar to a `TypeVar` and will solve your problem. It's currently planned for Python 3.10 and will be supported for older versions using `typing_extensions`

There you would write:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

def my_decorator(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, Container[T]]:

    def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Container[T]:
        return Container(f(*args, **kwargs))

    return cast(Callable[P, Container[T]], wrapper)
```

mypy support for PEP 612 isn't finished yet: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8645. Same with pytype (Google's python typechecker).

pyright (Microsoft's python typechecker) and pyre (facebook's python typechecker) do already support PEP 612